# The execution plan for mixed LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN in SQL query

Tags: sql, join, relational-database

I am testing a in-house relational DB and I cannot figure out the why the optimizer could figure out this query plan.

```
SELECT * from A LEFT JOIN B on A.x = B.x INNER JOIN C on B.y = C.y
```

The execution plan reported by this database could be written like below psuedo-code:

```
For each tupleB in B
   For each tupleC in C
     INNER JOIN tupleB and tupleC
     For each tupleA in A
         INNER JOIN tupleA
```

The result for this plan is correct.

If all the JOINs are INNER joins, this plan looks reasonable to me since INNER JOIN is both commutative and associative.

However, when the `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` are mixed, how does the optimizer could figure out `INNER_JOIN(INNER_JOIN(B,C),A)` share the same result with `INNER_JOIN(LEFT_JOIN(A,B),C)`?

Is there a theory to prove this or this just happens case by case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence of plans `INNER_JOIN(LEFT_JOIN(A,B),C)` and `INNER_JOIN(INNER_JOIN(B,C),A)` has two steps:

1. `INNER_JOIN(LEFT_JOIN(A,B),C)` is equivalent to `INNER_JOIN(INNER_JOIN(A,B),C)`
2. `INNER_JOIN(INNER_JOIN(A,B),C)` is equivalent to `INNER_JOIN(INNER_JOIN(B,C),A)`

The first equivalence is the more difficult to see. Once you perform `LEFT_JOIN(A,B)` you may have rows from `A` not having a counterpart in `B`. These rows are the only rows that are not in `INNER_JOIN(A,B)`. These rows will have NULL values in `B` attributes. Subsequently, you perform an inner join with `C` using `B.y` and those extra rows have to disappear in the final result since the `B.y` is NULL and the join condition `B.y = C.y` is always evaluated to `uknown`. Therefore, in the final result you have only those rows which are product of `INNER_JOIN(A,B)` even if you process the `LEFT_JOIN(A,B)`.

The second equivalence is commes from the [join associativity](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/354/zaiane/material/notes/Chapter12/node6.html)

Comment: is there any book or theory discuss those transformations? Thanks.

Comment: Many transformations are based on the relational algebra rewriting rules (see the link provided in my answer). More sophisticated rewritings such us unnesting are described in scientific articles, but they can be difficult to read.

Comment: Consider reading some classical DBMS book such as https://wiki.epfl.ch/provenance2011/documents/foundations%20of%20databases-abiteboul-1995.pdf There is always some chapter dealing with different query optimizations.